# convert statistics.stdev values to np.std value

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Is there a way to manually convert the values outputted from statistics.stdev to the value outputted from np.std? I know one takes the standard deviation of the population and the other takes the standard deviation of the sample.

statistics.stdev([10, 8, 2]) = 4.163331998932266
np.std([10, 8, 2]) = 3.39934634239519

Comment: `statistics.pstdev([10, 8, 2])` = `3.39934634239519`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `statistics.stdev()` returns the square root of the variance calculated by dividing the sum of squared deviations from the mean by the whole sample size `n`, whereas `np.std()` returns the square root of the variance calculated by dividing the sum of squared deviations from the mean by `n - 1` (to have an unbiased estimator).

So the factor to convert the one estimate of the standard deviation into the other is the square root of `(n - 1) / n`:

```py
import statistics

sample = [10, 8, 2]
n = len(sample)

statistics.stdev(sample) * ((n - 1) / n) ** 0.5
```

```
3.3993463423951904
```